# flash text with different color at every 500ms javascript

Tags: javascript, html, web

I am trying to create a simple javascript script that would flash a text with different color at every 500ms. I thought of something like this, but it doesn't work, it just prints out the text in a single color(one of the three green, black or red). Thanks for any help

```
<html>
<body >
<script>

var f = function() { 
var str = "Hello World";;
var d = new Date();
var n = d.getTime();
switch(n%3)
  {
  case 1:
  fontcolor="green"
  break;
  case 2:
  fontcolor="black"
  break;
  default:
  fontcolor="red"
  }
document.write(str.fontcolor(fontcolor));   
 }
setInterval(f, 500);     
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Do you mean creating a new element every time? Or alternating a set of colors for a single text element?

Comment: I mean alternating a set of colors for a single text element

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with something like this (refer to the comments to understand what is going on):

```
// Wait until the document is ready

window.onload = function()
{
    // Create the element

    var txt = document.createElement('span');

    txt.innerHTML = 'Hello World!';

    // Insert the element to the document

    document.body.appendChild(txt);

    // Alternate the colors

    var colors  = [ 'red', 'green', 'blue', 'black', 'yellow', 'pink' ];
    var current = 0;

    setInterval(function()
    {
        // Update element's style with the new color

        txt.style.color = colors[current];

        // Go to the next color

        current = (current + 1) % colors.length;

    }, 500);
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I have just run it in a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/q5Fw7/), and it seems to work. It looks like that as it is happening every 500ms, it is possible that the time between each call on your computer is actually 501ms (or some other exact divisor of 3), or some other divisor of 3. Why don't you try an aggregate counter, which is initially 0, then added d.getTime() % 1000 each time, then have that value % 3.

```
var a = 0;
var f = function() { 
    var str = "Hello World";;
    var d = new Date();
    var n = d.getTime();
    a = a + (n % 1000);
    switch(a % 3) {
        case 1:
            fontcolor="green"
            break;
        case 2:
            fontcolor="black"
            break;
        default:
            fontcolor="red"
    }
    document.write(str.fontcolor(fontcolor));
}
setInterval(f, 500);
```

Comment: sorry I accidentally edited your post..i tried the code again but it doesn't work, perhaps it is the way i execute it. i simply embed the code above in a html page and display it on a localhost server